# how to output a MYSQL Database Backup file without saving the file first?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, backup

I have the below script which is not working as it should:

The script should create a sql file for my database and output the file directly instead of saving it but instead i am getting an empty file!!

please help!

```
// Connect to database
$connection = @mysql_connect($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die(mysql_error());
$db = @mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die(mysql_error());


//get all of the tables
    $tables = array();
    $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $tables[] = $row[0];
    }

//cycle through
foreach($tables as $table)
{
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

    $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
    $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
            for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
            {
                $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
            }
            $return.= ");\n";
        }
    }
    $return.="\n\n\n";
}


$FileName = $db_name . '_' . date("d-m-y") . '.sql';

header('Content-Type: application/sql'); 
header("Content-length: " . filesize($NewFile)); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $FileName . '"'); 
echo $return; 

exit();
```

Update #1: I cannot use mysqldump as i am on shared hosting and shell exec() is diabled

Comment: Why not just wrap around [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html)?

Comment: You can use `mysqldump` to get a backup of your database

Comment: i am on shared hosting and shell_exec() or exce() is disabled.

Comment: Any answer for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap around [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html):

```php
<?=shell_exec("mysqldump -h $server -u $dbusername -p$dbpassword $db_name");?>
```

Note that you should really escape the variable terms of the command with [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php), but I ommitted it for brevity.

Comment: i am on shared hosting and shell_exec() or exce() is disabled.